# Forward MacOS App Key Press to iOS Simulator

Tags: macos

I want to forward all the key press events received by a running MacOS app to iOS Simulator.

I using `runningApplications(withBundleIdentifier:)` to get the `pid` of the running iOS Simulator.
Then I have my MacOS application listen to any key press events, and use `CGEvent` `postToPID` to forward the received keycode.

```
var pid: pid_t!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let runningApplications = NSRunningApplication.runningApplications(withBundleIdentifier: "com.apple.iphonesimulator")
    pid = runningApplications[0].processIdentifier

    NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown) {
        (event) -> NSEvent? in
        self.keyPressDown(with: event)
        return event
    }
}

func keyPressDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    print(event.keyCode)
    let cgEvent = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: event.keyCode, keyDown: true)
    cgEvent?.postToPid(pid)
}
```

This is code I'm using. This code snippet works for forwarding the key press event from the runing MacOS app to other applications, I tested on Firefox browse, Sublime Text.

Why is iOS Simulator not receiving those key press event.